# Entity Framework | log the SQL generated by the System.Data.Entity.DbContext

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I get the idea that I can use the following for SQL statements

Database.Log = (data) =>
                {
                    LogManager.Log(data, LogManager.Severity.Info,  false);
                };

However, what I have been finding that the behavior is such that when the script is unsuccessful, the above action i.e. Database.Log(...) is not called at all.

If it is true then I would like to catch the exception when .SaveChanges(...) has been called. I would want to get the SQL Script that has been executed. Please advise.

Comment: where are you actually logging. hope you are doing in dbtxt ctor...

Comment: @Saravanan Yes. It is in DbContext

Comment: What about command interception? http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/EntityFramework6/database-command-interception.aspx. Using `Database.Log` is not so good beacuse toy will log all or nothing. But when you use command interception you can try-catch only `NonQueryExecuting` and log the commnad.

Comment: this should definitely help you https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/dn469464.aspx